# How do I make a button that can both make my paragraph have a bigger and smaller font in Java script and HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried almost everything my newbie brain knows about js and nothing is yet to work. If anyone has an answer or solution that would be really helpful.

```js
function biggerfont() {
   let bf = document.getElementById("font");
   let btn = document.getElementById('btn');

   if (bf.style.fontSize == "25px") {
           bf.style.fontSize = "100px";
            btn.innerHTML = "Smaller"
 }
 else if (bf.style.fontSize == "100 px") {
     bf.style.fontSize = "25px";    
     btn.innerHTML = "Bigger"
 }
```

```html
 <p id="font" style="font-size: 25px;">Lorem Ipsum</p>

    <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="biggerfont()">Bigger</button>
```

Comment: Two typos: second condition should use "100px" not "100 px" and you're missing a closing curly bracket for the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without getting into production-grade ways of doing this: You forgot a closing curly brace at the end. Also, you typed `100 px` with a space instead of `100px`. Correcting those will make your code work.

Now, about good practices, because you are learning and this stuff gets overlooked easily, you forgot to end two statements with semicolons. In Javascript, ending with semicolon is not required, but since you're learning it is a good learning practice to get used to semicolons, to be consistent and end every line with a semicolon. You also need to learn to keep indentation consistent, this makes your code more readable. Lastly, be consistent and use either single quotes `'` or double quotes `"` at every string you type. Good luck in your learning journey!

```js
function biggerfont() {
    let bf = document.getElementById("font");
    let btn = document.getElementById("btn");

    if (bf.style.fontSize == "25px") {
        bf.style.fontSize = "100px";
        btn.innerHTML = "Smaller";
    }
    else if (bf.style.fontSize == "100px") {
        bf.style.fontSize = "25px";    
        btn.innerHTML = "Bigger";
    }
}
```

```html
<p id="font" style="font-size: 25px;">Lorem Ipsum</p>
<button type="button" id="btn" onclick="biggerfont()">Bigger</button>
```

Comment: Double quotes for HTML and single quotes for JS is a good guideline.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `}`. Also, remove the space in `100 px`

```js
function biggerfont() {
  let bf = document.getElementById("font");
  let btn = document.getElementById('btn');

  if (bf.style.fontSize == "25px") {
    bf.style.fontSize = "100px";
    btn.innerHTML = "Smaller"
  } else if (bf.style.fontSize == "100px") {
    bf.style.fontSize = "25px";
    btn.innerHTML = "Bigger"
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="font" style="font-size: 25px;">Lorem Ipsum</p>
<button type="button" id="btn" onclick="biggerfont()">Bigger</button>
```

Comment: It doesn't work the way the OP needs.

Comment: @ths It works fine. I tried it

Comment: No, it doesn't. It increases the font size but when you click it again it does nothing but it's supposed to decrease the font size. You may check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73999186/how-do-i-make-a-button-that-can-both-make-my-paragraph-have-a-bigger-and-smaller/73999311?noredirect=1#answer-73999341) to see the actual behavior needed.

Comment: @ths Oops! I had forgotten to remove the space lol

Answer (score 0):

You may simply check if the current `font-size` is `25px` then set it to `100px` otherwise set it back to `25px`.

Here's a live demo:

```js
const fontEl = document.getElementById("font"),
  btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  fontEl.style.fontSize = (fontEl.style.fontSize == '25px' ? 100 : 25) + 'px';
});
```

```css
#font {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<p id="font" style="font-size: 25px;">Lorem Ipsum</p>
<button type="button" id="btn">Adjust Font Size</button>
```

You may build on the above demo as it only serves a small push in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good case for using CSS. There's a [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) method that you can use with [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) that will allow you to add/remove a class from an element, and in your example you can do that within the click handler for your button.

```js
// Cache the elements outside of the function
const para = document.querySelector('p');
const btn = document.querySelector('button');

// Add a click listener to the button that calls the
// `handleClick` function when it's fired
btn.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

// Use classList's toggle method to
// toggle between a paragraph with a bigger class
// and a paragraph without a bigger class - click once
// to add the class, and click again to remove it.
// You can also set the text content of the button
// to match the what clicking on it is meant to do next
function handleClick() {
  para.classList.toggle('bigger');
  if (btn.textContent === 'Bigger') {
    btn.textContent = 'Smaller';
  } else {
    btn.textContent = 'Bigger';
  }
}
```

```css
p { font-size: 25px; }
button:hover { cursor: pointer; }
.bigger { font-size: 50px; }
```

```html
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<button type="button">Bigger</button>
```

Additional documentation

- [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)